# What does it mean when someone say "I prefer to use the old Saxon word wo-wo-word"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

Earlier today I asked a question on [Stack Exchange Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/36705/what-are-the-benefits-of-reducing-zeroes-from-currency-eg-iran) asking about the benefits of a certain scheme.

A user replied as follows

> Instead of the word "benefit" I prefer to use the old Saxon word "bebebebebebebebebebenefit". Some people say using the shorter word has bebebebebebebebebebenefits, but I don't see any.

These are not English words and I am aware of that. What does the speaker imply by saying `I prefer to use the old Saxon word extended-word` ?

I tried to read what those words could mean:

1. Saxon, according to Wikipedia

> Anglo-Saxon is the earliest historical form of the English language, spoken in England and southern and eastern Scotland in the early Middle Ages

2. Assuming it is an informal expression, I tried finding any phrases like `I prefer to use the old Saxon word` but couldn't find any.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the "wordplay" being queried here would mean nothing at all to most native speakers

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica then it was an incorrect usage of the `old saxon word` phrase.

Comment: I think the linked answer is "[taking the mickey](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mickey)". The change will need less ink rather than coins, because instead of bank notes saying '10,000,000 rial' they only need to be  '1,000 toman'.

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. It's not *particularly* witty, imho, but he's just making the point that meaningless repetition / extension / inflation / padding can occur anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am a native speaker and have never heard this phrase, I did some research and think I have a strong guess at what was intended.

[Alliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration) is a common literary device where certain syllables are repeated. This is used, rather than rhyming, in the form of poetry called [Alliterative verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliterative_verse), and had its origins in the Germanic languages, which would include [Old Saxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Saxon).

So it would seem to me the quote's author was adding unnecessary, alliterative repetition to the beginning of the word in the same way that one might add useless 000s to denominations of currency.